# How to set Time Picker time on "Done" click for Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am facing one issue that time gets changed every time I scroll time in time picker, how to set time only when done clicked in time picker, this issue is specifically for iOS.

Comment: What platform did you work?Xamarin.Forms for iOS  or Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Its Xamarin.Forms for iOS.